# Not able to access json data assigned to ViewData in MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I read the `JSON` file and assigned it to `ViewData` as follows

```
var jsonReader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/QandAFile.json"));
var rawJson = jsonReader.ReadToEnd();
jsonReader.Close();
var dtls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<QandA>>(rawJson);//Get List Of all Data Json File
var result = dtls.Take(1);
ViewData["Qu"] = result;
return View();
```

In my View I do as follows

```
@using EntityJsonModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewQuResult";
    var data = ViewData["Qu"] as QandA;
}
```

Accessing data is as follows

```
<label class="col-sm-8">@data.Quoation</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
       <input type="radio" value="@data.Option1" id="q1" name="q1">@data.Option1<br />
       <input type="radio" value="@data.Option2" id="q1" name="q1">@data.Option2<br />
       <input type="radio" value="@data.Option3" id="q1" name="q1">@data.Option3<br />
       <input type="radio" value="@data.Option4" id="q1" name="q1">@data.Option4<br />
  </div>
```

But I am getting null reference.I tried a whole lot of thing but not able to make it.

Let me know how to access this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your variable `dtls` `null` or it gets null when assigned to `ViewData["Qu"]`?

Comment: no I am getting the list of data I wish to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
var result = dtls.Take(1);
```

I used the below code and it worked for me

```
if (dtls.Count > 0)
{
    var result = dtls.ElementAt(0);
    ViewData["Qu"] = result;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: what does dtls.Take(1) return ?